# Firmar un mensaje Soap con X509Certificate C#

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, criptografía

Me encuentro desarrollando una solución de facturación electrónica DIAN-Colombia y estoy en el proceso de crear y firmar digitalmente el mensaje SOAP para comunicarme con el web service de validación previa. La estructura del mensaje SOAP que genera SOAPUI es la siguiente:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047238386">
            <wsu:Created>2020-07-31T14:12:03.838Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2020-08-01T06:52:03.838Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237291">MIIItTCCBp2gAwIBAgIIV95ucy/ByMg...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237825" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa soap wcf" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237744">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap wcf" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>F0BbpkmIW7M5fHl1I+sdhBG9qHKarFNxJGdGuH1Z5lM=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>cmBzdA3N9fNlsFgcDbMJwCj4QnIOw+WxiXVcG4zioLeAeDi0R3w1Yt0B3bzBn3KgEJPzTSy/vW+AdnZ/Q2JOeUfnXkGNa7d4lP3chygityViqVbEGQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237682">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237713">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237291" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:Action>http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/SendBillSync</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To wsu:Id="id-261F6C1DB8F3AFA22D15962047237744" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>
```

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento para generar la firma del mensaje SOAP:

```
         XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(ruta);

            var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

            ns.AddNamespace("soap", soap.NamespaceName);
            ns.AddNamespace("wsse", wsse.NamespaceName);
            ns.AddNamespace("ec", ec.NamespaceName);
            ns.AddNamespace("ds", ds.NamespaceName);
            ns.AddNamespace("wsu", wsu.NamespaceName);
        
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            var signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(xmlDoc);

            var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();                
            
            XmlElement x = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse", "SecurityTokenReference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            XmlElement y = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse", "Reference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            x.SetAttribute("Id", wsu.NamespaceName, "STR-" + this.GetSecurityTokenReferenceID());
            y.SetAttribute("URI", "#X509-" + this.GetBinarySecurityTokenID());
            y.SetAttribute("ValueType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3");
            x.AppendChild(y);
            var keyInfoData = new KeyInfoNode(x);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
            keyInfo.Id = "KI-" + this.GetKeyInfoID();                
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
         
            signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

            signedXml.Signature.Id = "SIG-" + this.GetSignatureID();
            signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
           
            XmlDsigExcC14NTransform canMethod = (XmlDsigExcC14NTransform)signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject;
            canMethod.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
            canMethod.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = _canonicaMethodPrefixList;                                    

            XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
            env.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";                           
            env.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = _transformPrefixList;

            var reference = new Reference { Uri = "#id-" + this.ID };
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            var signedElement = signedXml.GetXml();

            SetPrefix("ds", signedElement);
            
            var nodoSecurity = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//wsse:Security", ns) as XmlElement;
            nodoSecurity.AppendChild(signedElement);

            xmlDoc.Save(ruta);
```

Y a continuacion lo que genera dicho codigo:

```
<Signature Id="SIG-5e21d3291c4240d59c17659c06ea811b" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa soap wcf" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </CanonicalizationMethod>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <Reference URI="#id-702f0abae9ab446783a2b0bb1a47e163">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap wcf" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>9NsYFHBFhdgVivZas6XW7pYXG/unN9k1+mEubpvF+SQ=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>WbVdox/6W6NU5hzE83Lpmonu/7nsGJj3N6aQQySBz+sAYDyY7FZ1GefQsRUZ3L8wwNThP52majeNtCnE2xJ4u5AHqt3VYZ4/kLap0ya7wIa/XUIGsZA/gCurNl8Xwb70GIWvttTIzTyu5JlfF3w6QQt/UINJ8Fysupk4CmoMPus=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo Id="KI-af4cbe1efbed4efc973aac357c086c2f">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-2367a492da7d44e6862444c8d9c3bcf3">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-1f801956043443f290ef048e4d1100cb" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Tengo problemas para insertar los prefijos para el grupo de nodos **Signature** como los genera SOAPUI:
**ds:**
**wsse:** (wsse:SecurityTokenReference)
**ec:**   (< ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap wcf" xmlns:**ec**="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>)

Tengo entendido que un documento después que se ha insertado la firma no puede modificarse y debido a esto quisiera recibir alguna ayuda para corregir el problema y generar un mensaje SOAP valido.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: Pero no vas a modificar el documento sino la firma.

Comment: Hola Miguel. El problema es tratando de modificar la información de la Firma (Signature).